# why bundle using the lower version of ruby

Tags: ruby

when I using bundle update in macOS Catalina 10.15:

```
$ bundle update                                                                                                                                                                ‹ruby-3.0.0›
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies....
Bundler found conflicting requirements for the Ruby version:
  In Gemfile:
    Ruby

    fastlane (= 2.177.0) was resolved to 2.177.0, which depends on
      Ruby (>= 2.4)

    fastlane (= 2.177.0) was resolved to 2.177.0, which depends on
      google-api-client (< 0.39.0, >= 0.37.0) was resolved to 0.38.0, which depends on
        Ruby (~> 2.4)

    xcode-install was resolved to 2.6.8, which depends on
      Ruby (>= 2.0.0)
(base)
```

and then check my ruby version:

```
$ ruby -v                                                                                                                                                                      ‹ruby-3.0.0›
ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-darwin19]
(base)
```

why the bundle not using the 3.0.0 version ruby?

Answer (score 1):

It is because `google-api-client` declares that it depends on `Ruby (~> 2.4)`, which means "anything upwards 2.4, provided it's still 2.*".

Try to upgrade google-api-client, and if it does not have a version compatible with ruby 3, downgrade your ruby.

Comment: are you sure downgrade ruby not upgrade? @rewritten

Comment: google-api-client wants a lesser version than you have, so yes, you need to downgrade.